# Adding a Selector To My Iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, popup

I'm using colorbox for a popup that comes up on page load, and it's using inline CSS for width and height within the script. However, I need to use media queries to change the width and height for smaller screens, but I don't know how to access the code from my CSS. I've tried adding an ID and a class where the width and height currently are but none of them seem to work, and I have very, very limited knowledge of this. Pasting the code below to show the inline CSS that's currently being used. I want to move that over to my CSS document:

```
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
  function openColorBox(){
    $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"600px", height:"450px", href: "popup.html"});
  }

  setTimeout(openColorBox, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Colorbox API](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) defines a `className` parameter to add a class.

Comment: Even with adding this, every time I take the inline styles out and put them into my CSS, it will no longer show up. And if I keep the inline styles in there, it ignores the styles that I try to add in my CSS

Comment: Are the styles getting crossed out when you inspect the element in your browser's development tools? You may need to use `!important` in your CSS (example: `width: 600px !important;`) to override the sizes added by Colorbox via JS.